# ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist with entity framework

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I'm new to asp.net mvc and the entity framework and i'm trying to make a dropdownlist with data out of my database. I have the following:

Controler:

```
//
// GET: /StoreEditor/Edit/(ID)
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   StoreEditorViewModel data = new StoreEditorViewModel(id);

   return View(data);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public StoreEditorViewModel(int id)
    {
        using (MvcTicketsEntities storeDB = new MvcTicketsEntities())
        {
            details = (from t in storeDB.Tickets.Include("Artists").Include("Genres")
                       where t.TicketId == id
                       select t).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Now i get get all my labels and editors in de view. But how do i make a dropdownlist with all the names in the database table GENRES in the field NAME.

The table GENRES has 2 fields GenreId and Name.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below link:
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

This explains quite well, how to approach it.

Basically, you would need to create `List<SelectListItem>` object and supply it to the dropdown list.

Thanks